# JSFiddle: How to specify that the script is run as a module?

Tags: javascript, import, module, jsfiddle

Some features such as `await` don't work unless the javascript file is loaded as `type="module"`.  However, in JSFiddle, there doesn't seem to be a way to achieve this.   Setting the Framework Script Attribute to 'type="module"' does nothing.

Is there any way to make JSFiddle import the main script as a module?

Example not working: https://jsfiddle.net/x9L2eqmo/1/

```
async function f1(x) {
  return x * 2;
}
x = await f1(5);
console.log(x)
```

Comment: What about adding your code between `<script>` tags, and add `type="module"`?

Comment: @LightningMcQueen doesn't that sort of defeat the purpose of the JSFiddle layout?  Sure I could do that but that's not how JSFiddle is made to be used...

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think Stack Overflow is a support desk for JSFiddle. Anyway, there's no other solution than the one I wrote about. Actually, this was [discussed before](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/1056).

Comment: @LightningMcQueen so the simple answer is "this is not supported".  No need to be snarky.

Comment: I wasn't snarky, seems like I sounded snarky, really never intended to :-) What I meant is there's no such thing, even it was discussed on GitHub, and yet the issue isn't solved from JSFiddle's side.